# my mouse scroll wheel doesn't scroll

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, sp3, mouse-wheel

It's only a minor thing but i can't solve it.

I have  a ps2 mouse on win xp sp3. the wheel has stopped scrolling in all apps however in apps that support it i can click the wheel and bring up the scrolling four way arrows and scroll that way.

I've tried uninstalling the drivers and changing the wheel settings but to no effect.

It obviously recognises the wheel since i can click it.

Any ideas super users?!

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse? The wheel rotation sensor might be bad.

Comment: Your answer is in here, how about awarding somebody the answer vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wheel click and wheel rotation are to completely separate sensors. You've got a broken mouse on your hands.

Comment: right you are. i didn't realise the two were different or i would have assumed it was broken...

Answer (score 1):

The scroll wheel works by breaking a beam of light with spokes in the wheel. If there is dirt in the small spokes the the beam of light is always broken and scrolling won't work. Open up the mouse or trackball and blow out the dirt. I just installed a different trackball to ensure that scrolling works in the OS. It does. So I cleaned out the one that didn't work and now it does.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is improbable that all the holes in the wheel would be filled by dirt. Normally when dirty it should work at least partially. There could also be some dirt on the LED or sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: make sure the scroll options are still turned on. This is done in the mouse setting in the control panel.

Option 2: Get a new mouse. Yours does sound broken. :)